# Can somebody help me with a simple mesh manipulation (Dome Architecture)

Tags: mesh, modifiers

I am new to blender, and I need help with a simple mesh manipulation.

This is a garden from [Howl's Moving Castle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Howl%27s_Moving_Castle_(film)) and I am trying to build a basic structure of it.

[image]

And this is what I have so far
[image]

Outside looks fine but inside looks like this

[image]

I need to find out a way to get rid of the yellow part and the red part as well.
I have tried boolean modifier but it does not seem to get rid of the red part.

Can someone help me with it. I mean if there is an easier way, it will also be very much appreciated.

Comment: Hello, maybe share your file so that we can help you? pasteall.org/blend (copy paste the link it will give once you've uploaded your file)

Comment: Do you want to keep it non-destructive? If not, can't you simply apply the modifier and delete all the faces you do not want? Maybe it's not perfect and you have to do some mesh cleaning up afterwards...

Comment: Did not know I can add a file. I will add a file in the future. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe use another method to build it, create a circle object, put it on the side, use it to cut a shape on your dome with the *Knife Project* tool (select the circle object, shift select the dome object, go in *Edit* mode then go into the *Mesh panel > Knife Project*):

[image]

[image]

[image]

Clean up the cut shape with some <kbd>X</kbd> > vertices and edges dissolve, make it go down to the bottom:

[image]

Extrude, then symmetrize, etc:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This gives me more precise result.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the *Boolean Modifier* set to *Union* (and unfortunately always a bit depending on how the vertices are placed) you can almost immediately get the result you want. The geometry might not be perfect since the *Boolean Modifier* creates bad geometry most of the time, but if you apply it you can always clean up the mesh.

[image: boolean_union]

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Did not know I could do it with Union. But boolean sometimes does not give me exact result that I want...

Comment: @김양욱 I know... as I said, it's sometimes depending on how well the vertices are placed and the geometry isn't always great and needs a lot of cleaning afterwards. Some people even give the advice never to use the Boolean modifier. But I usually take it as a starting point from where I can further refine the mesh.

Comment: I see. I will take your advice in the future for some other projects if needed. Thanks )